When we should integrate on both side over a SDE?
Maybe I am quite stupid, I am quite confused about, when we should use ito formula to solve SDE and when it is appropriate to integrate directly to get the solution?
Specifically, let us consider the following three SDEs, The first one is:
$$dX_t=b_tdt+\sigma_tdB_t,$$
In this case, we directly integrate on both side, we get solution of the SDE!
The second is the GBM $$dX_t=X_t(b_t dt+\sigma_tdB_t),$$ we want to get the solution of GBM. we impose the new process $Z_t =ln X_t,$ by using ito formula, we will get the results given by GBM.
The last one is:  let us consider CIR stochastic process, simplify case, $$dY_t=aY_t dt+b\sqrt{Y_t}dB_t,$$ we multiply $e^{at}$ on both side, we define a new process $W_t=e^{-at} Y_t,$ by using ito formula, we get results $$dW_t=be^{-at} \sqrt{Y_t}dB_t,$$ but the integrand is depend on $Y_t,$  why we still integrate on both side get the solution?
So the question is when to use Itô's Lemma and when it is appropriate to integrate directly to get the solution?

It is unclear what you are asking. Ito’s lemma is just a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but for stochastic processes. So your question amounts to asking “when should you use the FTC”, which is an impossible question to answer in generality.

like the first  example, we also can integrate on both side right, then we will get some ito process? but we use transformation and ito formula.  in the second example, the last formula of the right side still depends on $Y_t$, but we integrate on both side? My confused point is when do you know you can integrate on both side and make sure that is your solution!

You know it when you see it. The CIR SDE does not have a closed form solution.
